# If I have a kernel version, can I get a list of CVEs it's vulnerable to?

Tags: linux, security, kernel, cve

So say I have a kernel version. Something like one of these:

```
3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64
3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
3.10.35-43.137.amzn1.x86_64
2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64
```

Is there a way to programmatically get a list of CVEs that that kernel version is vulnerable to? I know that if I know a CVE, I can easily see which kernel versions are vulnerable to it, but I'm looking to go the other way.